# Redirecting a site to https and non www .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I cant seem to find the answer I want to redirect to https and the non www version of a site

so http://www.example.com redirects to https://example.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```